Error Error when running the selected code generator: "Error restoring package. Reverting package changes for 'WebApp'."
Description: Hello everyone, I'm learning ASP.NET with C# and I'm having a problem trying to create an area in my project. Based on the tutorials I've followed, it should be as simple as:
Right click on Areas Select Add → Area. Write the name of the area and press "OK". However, when entering the name, Visual Studio shows an error and the area is not generated correctly. I have tried several solutions without success.
it say in the messagebox:
Error

Error running selected code generator: "Error restoring package.
Reverting package changes for 'WebApp'."

OK

I can't reproduce your issue, I shared my test progress below. What I used is VS 2022 + .NET 8 mvc application. According to your error message, I'm afraid you need to check the nuget packages installed in your app. Pay attention to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package, my .net 8 app will auto  install version 8.0.6 when I add MVC Area. But if I work on .net 6 app, it will auto install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design  V6.0.18. And you might clean and rebuild the solution and test again. By the way, may I know which tutorial you are following?

According to OP's confirmation, the issue is solved by Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool, so that it might be due to something wrong within the .Net SDK.
===============
Firstly, I can't reproduce your issue. In my side, when I right click on the Areas folder and Add Area, I choose MVC Area option then I enter the Area name. Next I will see pending dialog below.

After adding the MVC Area(I give the Area name as Admin), I will get an Admin folder and within the Admin folder, I have Controllers Data Models Views folders. Then inside the Controllers folder, I created a new MVC controller, then adding [Area("Admin")] attribute on the controller class.
[Area("Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

Right click on return View(); add select Add View.

Finally, adding Area routing in Program.cs, then we will be able to visit the Area view with url localhost:port/admin/home/index or /admin for visit the default controller action method.
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyArea",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


solve it by installing the following microsoft program solution: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Thanks for your sharing, I will get it updated into my post.
